# Minha imagem do chrome theme não preenche a tela toda. O que há de errado?

Tags: google-chrome-extensão

Eu estou criando um tema para Google Chrome, mas a imagem não preenche a tela toda. Já consultei a documentação, li alguns tutoriais, mas a minha imagem não preenche a tela toda do navegador.

Meu *manifest* está assim:

```json
{
  "version": "2015.0.1",
  "description": "Nanatsu no Taizai Extension",
  "name": "Nanatsu no Taizai",

  "theme": {
    "images": {
      "theme_frame_overlay": "img/overlay-40.png",
      "theme_toolbar": "img/toolbar-120.png",
      "theme_ntp_background": "img/background.png",
      "theme_button_background": "img/button_30.png",
      "theme_tab_background": "img/tab.png"
    },
    "color": {
      "frame": [10, 17, 27],
      "toolbar": [10, 17, 27],
      "ntp_text": [255, 255, 255],
      "ntp_link": [255, 255, 255],
      "ntp_setion": [10, 17, 27],
      "button_background": [10, 17, 27]
    },
    "tints": {
      "buttons": [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
    },
    "properties": {
      "ntp_background_alignment": "bottom",
      "ntp_background_repeat": "no-repeat"
    }
  },

  "author": "Josue",
  "manifest_version": 2

}
```

Abaixo o link da screensaver do meu navegador, com o *theme* "instalado".

<kbd>[image: imagem]</kbd>

O que há de errado com meu *manifest*?

Comment: Ninguém sabe ao menos um palpite do que pode está errado ?

Comment: Porque não utiliza uma aplicação que de para fazer um tema em que depois é só adicionar uma imagem ?

Comment: @SomeOneHelpMe Eu sou do tipo que gosta de "fazer por mim mesmo", por uma questão de aprendizado. No entanto, visitei o site [themebeta.com](http://www.themebeta.com/chrome-theme-creator-online.html) e notei na parte de *Background Image*, as opções normal size, fill screen e fit to screen. Testei cada uma delas na propriedade _"properties" : {
      "ntp_background_alignment" : "bottom"
    }_. Usei " *center fit to screen* ", e sucessivamente até dá certo.

Comment: Caso isso tenha resolvido o seu problema, coloque como resposta a sua pergunta, para que casp alguem tenha a mesma duvida, tenha aqui a resposta.